# How could I get all root level sites (excluding sub site) using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: rest, site, microsoft-graph, java-api

I could get all site (including root level site as well as sub site) by using the following url : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*

Is there a better way to get all the root level sites only (excluding the sub site) using Microsoft Graph API ?

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/site_list) says the following filter expression could be utilized to *list all root-level site collections*:

```
siteCollection/root ne null
```

But unfortunately i have not managed to get it working against `V1` endpoint. 
As a workaround you could consider to filter root-level site collections *on the client side*, here is C# example (utilizes [Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)):

```
var result = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Site>();
var requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*&select=webUrl,siteCollection";
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(message);
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);

var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var sites = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Microsoft.Graph.Site>>(JObject.Parse(content)["value"].ToString());
result = sites.Where(s => s.SiteCollection != null).ToList();
```

Comment: Sadly I havent been able to run on the beta endpoint the `/sites?$filter=siteCollection/root ne null` as documented, gives me very different results compared to the one that you suggest on the v1.0 endpoint.